# Why is Clippy warning me about a function which may panic?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am quite new to Rust and I stumbled upon this warning from Clippy in my codebase:

```
warning: docs for function which may panic missing `# Panics` section
    --> src/activity.rs:113:1                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▐
     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ▐
 113 | pub async fn running(db: &PgPool, user_id: String) -> anyhow::Result<Option<Running>> {                                                                                                                                      ▐
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                        ▐
     |
 note: first possible panic found here
    --> src/activity.rs:130:9
     |
 130 |         user_id
     |         ^^^^^^^
     = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#missing_panics_doc
     = note: `-W clippy::missing-panics-doc` implied by `-W clippy::pedantic`
     = help: to override `-W clippy::pedantic` add `#[allow(clippy::missing_panics_doc)]`
```

The connected code looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Running {
    id: sqlx::types::Uuid,
    user_id: String,
    name: String,
    start_time: chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>,
    end_time: Option<chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>>,
    tags: Vec<Tag>,
}

pub async fn running(db: &PgPool, user_id: String) -> anyhow::Result<Option<Running>> {
    let result = sqlx::query_as!(
        Running, 
        r#"
        SELECT 
            activities.*,
            COALESCE(array_agg((tags.id, tags.user_id, tags.name)) filter (WHERE tags.id IS NOT NULL), '{}') AS "tags!: Vec<Tag>"
        FROM activities
        LEFT JOIN activities_tags
            ON activities.id = activities_tags.activity_id
        LEFT JOIN tags
            ON activities_tags.tag_id = tags.id
        WHERE activities.user_id = $1 AND end_time IS NULL
        GROUP BY activities.id
        ORDER BY activities.start_time ASC
        LIMIT 1
        "#,
        user_id
    ).fetch_optional(db).await?;
    Ok(result)
}
```

I dug through the internet with this warning, but could not really find an answer or solution.

I am wondering two things:

1. Is this warning just because of the fact that sqlx 'panics' once the schema validation is wrong and thus carries this warning into runtime, which can not really happen?
2. Is there even anything I can do about the panic or is the normal with `sqlx` for example?

My thought process so far in Rust was that when it compiles you are pretty much good to go, but this warning makes me wonder, if there is still some run-time magic going on which have to be aware of?

Comment: Is there a name for violated clippy lint in this warning?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I've added the note to the original post, since the formatting is not great in the comment here. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Quickly skimming [issues for missing_panic_docs lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+missing_panics_doc) suggest that it can be buggy. If you don't really care about this lint you can either disable it for failing functions, or for whole crate.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze thanks for your quick response. Ok I have not looked into github, that is a good point. So looks quite like a false positive in this case?

Comment: Overall i'd say using `clippy::pedantic` is a mistake.

Comment: Might be a false positive, might also be a diagnostics issue, they sometimes don't highlight the right bit of code in combination with macros and `query_as` might actually panic. Trying to fix every `clippy::pedantic` lint definitely is a mistake, I think [its docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/clippy/usage.html#clippypedantic) also say that about itself.

Comment: You should never `#![warn(clippy::pedantic)]`. The lints there are meant to be selected one-by-one if you want one of them.

Comment: Isn't it normal that `sqlx::query_as!` could panic, since it's trying to convert to specific types and the conversion might fail (as OP said in point 1)?

Comment: @Codebling I think that is the reason since it has to panic or something for the compile time check. That is the thing I do not understand: `slqx` is checking the query against the schema and what type you provided, so at runtime it should 100% safe shouldn't it?

Comment: @conscience depends what you mean by safe. You're right that the logic should be sound, and that running the code should cause no problems. If we're talking about whether Rust should know that the code shouldn't panic, the answer is no. Fundamentally we're importing data from an external source, it's possible that the schema could have changed and the data types are no longer compatible. It makes sense that this code might panic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to shed some light on your issue. I stumbled upon the same issue today and I think I know the cause.

### Cause of the problem

The macro `query_as!` expands into something that contains panic.
If you follow how the macro expands you will find that for each parameter (`$1`, `user_id` in your case) of the query, the expanded macro contains this piece of code (link to github [here](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/sqlx-macros-core/src/query/args.rs#L78)):

```
// this shouldn't actually run
if false {
    use ::sqlx::ty_match::{WrapSameExt as _, MatchBorrowExt as _};

    // evaluate the expression only once in case it contains moves
    let expr = ::sqlx::ty_match::dupe_value(#name);

     // if `expr` is `Option<T>`, get `Option<$ty>`, otherwise `$ty`
     let ty_check = ::sqlx::ty_match::WrapSame::<#param_ty, _>::new(&expr).wrap_same();

     // if `expr` is `&str`, convert `String` to `&str`
     let (mut _ty_check, match_borrow) = ::sqlx::ty_match::MatchBorrow::new(ty_check, &expr);

     _ty_check = match_borrow.match_borrow();

     // this causes move-analysis to effectively ignore this block
     ::std::panic!();
}
```

Clippy then thinks this panic can happen, when in reality it can't.

### Side note

Interesting is that authors of the library thought about clippy. At the start of the expanded macro is `#[allow(clippy::all)]` (link to github [here](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/sqlx-macros-core/src/query/mod.rs#L335)). But for some reason it doesn't allow panics.

### Solution

Probably not needed anymore but anyway, my advice is to use `#[allow(clippy::panic)]` before each query. Or you can put it on module which contains your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I did not want to have this post here hanging around like that.

As pointed out by `Chayim Friedman` that pedantic might not be the right set of lints.

I've decided to keep it for the time being, since I hope that I am pointed to more issues like this one even though they might be a 'false positive'.

As `Codebling` pointed out that the `query_as!` macro is highly likely to panic or at least it is presumed to panic. My current understanding for this section is that I can safely ignore the panic warning, since `query_as!` should not panic at runtime, because `sqlx` checks against the database with the provided type and input if everything checks out. So I think I trust it for now.